# Android: Using several version of the same library for different flavors

Tags: android, dependencies, android-productflavors

I'm needing help again with my strange projects ;)

So I'm still building a library, and I need to use libA-1.01.jar and libA-2.1.jar

Of course I don't want them in the same flavor, so I used in my gradle file:

```
flavorACompile files('libs/libA-1.01.jar')
flavorBCompile files('libs/libA-2.1.jar')
```

This works fine when compiling with gradlew in command line. But the issue is that my classes don't see both libraries. So when I'm coding I can only import the first one (1.01). So I can't use my IDE to code properly I have to guess emacs style if everything is ok and compile to see...

How can I tell Android Studio that the 2 libraries are present? I tried added them both to compile without flavor (just to force android studio to use them) but it didn't work.

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, but I can't seem to find it :(